# android custom layout overriding one another while using 'include'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a repeating layout component as below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widgetSettingsEntry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEntryIcon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEntryName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgEntryIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvEntryValue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgEntryIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgEntryIcon" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEntryValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgEntryIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgEntryIcon" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It overrides one another when trying to include the above in the main layout multiple times, using the `include` keyword to include layout in the main layout(below).

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layoutUserSettings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            layout="@layout/widget_settings_entry"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <view
            android:id="@+id/vb1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="@color/colorRatingBarFill"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/line2"
            layout="@layout/widget_settings_entry"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vb1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "overrides one another"?

Comment: including the above layout in another layout repeatedly by using  `include<>`. But the all included ones stay on top of one another though provided start/end/top/bottom constrains. Using the ConstraintLayout in the main layout too.

Comment: the intention is to include the above layout repeatedly using `include<>` and separated by ConstraintLayout's `Guideline`.

Comment: Oh, you mean overlaps? You can set `id`s and `layout_*` attributes on the `<include>` elements, just like you would on any other `<View>`. If you're having trouble with that, you'll want to post the main layout, too.

Comment: Question updated with main layout. In which I tried with `Guideline` instead of `View` but had no luck.

Comment: OK, cool. I don't use `ConstraintLayout`, though, so hopefully somebody more familiar with it can help you with that. I originally thought your question was about conflicting IDs in the multiple `<include>`s, which is why I thought I could help. Anyhoo, good luck to ya. Cheers!